# Extending simplicial complex to a manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $Y$ be a simplicial complex contained in a simplex $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Can I find a simplicial complex $X\supseteq Y$ s.t. $|X|=|S|$? Moreover, can I do it without introducing new vertices, apart from $Y^{(0)}$ and $S^{(0)}$?

If this is too basic for this site, let me know please. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "a simplicial complex contained in $S$"? Do you mean $|X|$ can be embedded into $S$?

Comment: I mean, Y is realized in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $|Y|\subseteq |S|$.